# Philosophers that would be of particular interest to engineers/designers?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, history-of-philosophy, aesthetics

Does anyone know of philosophers that would be of particular interest to mathematicians/engineers/designers ?

Comment: As written, this is largely opinion-based. Can you give us clearer guidelines on what in philosophy such an individual would find interesting?

Comment: For mathematics Hermann Weyl might be interesting. Perhaps Heinrich Schenker? George Spencer Brown? Rudolph Steiner had a lot to say about design and architecture.

Comment: Occam's razor may be useful. Ludwig Wittgenstein was a mathematician and engineer. Actually, a lot of the early philosophers did everything (philosophy, science, math). But anyway, I'm with virmaior--there needs to be more in the description.

Answer (score 1):

**[Plato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato)**.  His theory of ["Forms,"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-metaphysics/) ideal, perfect, abstract conceptual entities, continues to have a currency [among mathematicians](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics/) it has largely lost elsewhere, and is also of continuing interest to engineers and designers.

Answer (score 0):

If what I heard is true, Swami Rama Tirtha, an Indian Sanyasin was one such philosopher.
Read more about him from this link:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama_Tirtha

Once I have read his visions connecting Philosophy and Mathematics.

Here is a quote from http://www.ramatirtha.org/rama.htm

> Rama was a brilliant student, especially in mathematics. After
>   completing his degree, he served for a while as Professor of
>   Mathematics in the Forman Christian College. It was at this stage that
>   his spiritual life began to blossom.